# How to display date and time picker for base field on custom entity

Tags: 8, entities, datetime

I've made a base field on a custom entity with type "datetime" using "datetime_default" for the form display. It's displaying as only a date picker, with no time component, whereas I want it to look like this:

[image: Date picker with time component]

If I create a field in the GUI I can select between "date only" or "date and time". (The image above is the result of picking "date and time"). But I can't work out how to do this programmatically. I've tried creating fields of both types and exporting the config, but there is no difference between them, which is a mystery.

I suspect I need to put something other than "datetime_default" but I can't find any documentation on how to programmatically refer to the various date and time widgets.

```
public static function baseFieldDefinitions(EntityTypeInterface $entity_type) {
$fields = parent::baseFieldDefinitions($entity_type);

$fields['activity_date_time'] = BaseFieldDefinition::create('datetime')
  ->setLabel(t('Date and time'))
  ->setDescription('')
  ->setRevisionable(TRUE)
  ->setRequired(TRUE)
  ->setSettings([
    'datetime_type' => 'date'
  ])  
  ->setDefaultValueCallback('Drupal\opencase_entities\Entity\OCActivity::currentDateTime')
  ->setDisplayOptions('view', [
    'label' => 'above',
    'type' => 'datetime_default',
    'settings' => [
      'format_type' => 'medium',
    ],
    'weight' => -3, 
  ])  
  ->setDisplayOptions('form', [
    'type' => 'datetime_default',
    'weight' => -3, 
  ]);
```

Comment: `setSettings(['datetime_type' => 'date'])` this seems to be to blame.  See the switch in the source [here](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21datetime%21src%21Plugin%21Field%21FieldWidget%21DateTimeDefaultWidget.php/8.2.x) - if type is 'date' (implemented as a [const](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21datetime%21src%21Plugin%21Field%21FieldType%21DateTimeItem.php/constant/DateTimeItem%3A%3ADATETIME_TYPE_DATE/8.2.x)) then only show date form element, otherwise show date+ time elements.

Comment: You should put that as an answer to be up-voted.

Comment: Brilliant, thanks @stevekeiretsu! I just removed that "setSettings" bit and it worked. Please do put it as an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: I wasn't entirely sure if it would work, or whether naomi needed to remove that bit or replace it with something else.  I'll make it an answer now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`setSettings(['datetime_type' => 'date'])` - this seems to be to blame. See the switch [in the source here](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21datetime%21src%21Plugin%21Field%21FieldWidget%21DateTimeDefaultWidget.php/8.2.x) which effectively says if type is 'date' (implemented as a [const](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21datetime%21src%21Plugin%21Field%21FieldType%21DateTimeItem.php/constant/DateTimeItem%3A%3ADATETIME_TYPE_DATE/8.2.x)) then only show the date form element, otherwise show the date + time elements.

Comment: I wouldn't say this is 100% accurate.  The `setSettings(['datetime_type' => 'date'])` sets the field type to date-only (and you should really use `setSettings(['datetime_type' => DateTimeItem::DATETIME_TYPE_DATE])`.  When you remove that from the field definition, it uses the default value, which happens to be 'datetime', which is date+time.  Using `setSettings(['datetime_type' => DateTimeItem::DATETIME_TYPE_DATETIME])` would also have the same effect here.